# How to share a post in twitter using ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to share a post created in rails which is just a text content. Coding to share that post's title and url using this code

```
<a onclick="javascript:window.open('https://twitter.com/share?text=<%= @post.title %> by @rockyram6195 - &amp;url=<%= url_for([@post, {only_path: false}]) %>', '_blank', 'width=800, height=500, top=200, left=300');void(0);">
    <i class="fa fa-twitter">
</a>
```

But i don't know what the problem is but when i click it nothing happen .
any one tell me whats the problem or suggest me some other way of code to share my post's title and comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [pretty-social jquery plugin](https://github.com/sonnyt/prettySocial).
Add this in a javascript file:

```
$('.prettySocial').prettySocial();
```

To include the plugin, you can paste [the plugin file](https://github.com/sonnyt/prettySocial/blob/master/jquery.prettySocial.min.js) in your assets or vendor folder.

And this on your posts:

```
<div class="prettySocial" data-type="twitter" data-url="<%= request.original_url %>" data-description = "<%= @post.content %>" data-media = "<%= @post.main_photo %>"><%= image_tag("twitter.png")%>
```

You'll get a twitter icon, which will trigger a share onClick.

Comment: You might be able to find it bundled as a gem, but it's pretty easy just to copy/paste the code I shared in the link "the plugin file"